# Unable to install boot repair using Ubuntu live usb

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot, bootrepair

I'm installing Ubuntu 13.04 (16 bit ) along with Windows 7 in my Lenovo Thinkpad. I was able to install Ubuntu successfully. But, after installation it asked me to `restart now`. I clicked on it. It started windows without showing boot menu. Now, what should I do to get the boot menu at the start.

This are the steps I tried and was not successful :
1. After browsing I found that boot repair has to be installed. 
   I successfully used a Ubuntu live CD and tried to install the boot repair.
   I tried the following commands -

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

But, I get this error now,

```
dpkg: error: reading package into file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' : Input/output error
E: subprocess /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

how can I solve this problem to get a boot menu at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

That error message is connected with a package whose info is somehow corrupted in the dpkg database.

What you need to do is:

1. Go to the /var/lib/dpkg directory;
2. Backup of the "status" file (just in case; you may just call it ..status_old);
3. Edit the "status" file;
4. Search for the package that generated the error, in your case Boot-Repair;
5. Delete all the lines pertaining to this package, and only this package.

Careful: you will need to leave all lines that concern other packages even if they contain the broken package in their "Replaces" or "Depends" fields.

Answer (score 0):

When confronted to an unaccessible GNU/Linux system at boot, i use [Super Grub Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/).

Simply download Super Grub Disk and install it on a USB key or CD-ROM, and boot on your inaccessible GNU/Linux system. Once on your system, you just need to reinstall the GRUB boot loader.

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```